# Delete all double quotes from a string and then adding double quotes to it

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to solve this for a while today, I hope someone can help me.
I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import re


com = "\""
a = str(com)


df = pd.read_csv("xd.csv", sep = ',')

for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == object:
        df[column] = df[column].apply(str)
        for x in range(len(df)):
            re.sub('[\",\']','', df.loc[x,column])
            df.loc[x,column] =  a + df.loc[x,column] + a
```

I pretend to delete all double quotes from the strings of a DataFrame, and then adding double quotes again.
This is mainly because I have some strings that are like this:

"ALICATE Cte Obl 6" 1000V - HAMILTON"

And I want them to be like this:

"ALICATE Cte Obl 6 1000V - HAMILTON"

In other words, I want to delete those middle double quotes. But the problem is my code return them like this:

"""ALICATE Cte Obl 6 1000V - HAMILTON"""""

And the correct ones, that were like this:

"SIM CARD TV LEASE P6"

Are now like this:

"""SIM CARD TV LEASE P6"""

---

@uttam
I tried that and it keeps returning me triple double quoutes. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import re

df = pd.read_csv("xd.csv", sep = ',')


for i in range(len(df)):
    df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"][i].replace('[\"\,\.]','')
    df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"][i] = '"' + df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"][i] + '"'

df.to_csv("xd.csv", index=False)
```

Before: "MARTILLO C/FIBRA BOL.350GR - HAMILTON "

After: """MARTILLO C/FIBRA BOL.350GR - HAMILTON """

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters by using using `str.replace("what to replace","with what to replace")`

**Example**:- Suppose I have a column of price filled with $ . and , symbols but I wanna remove them then I can use `price_column=df["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]','')`

and after replacing try using concatenation property,

**Example**:- `" + df["Price"][0] + ")`

Answer (score 0):

Do the replacements on all rows at once, instead of the much slower process of iterating through rows.  Also, you need .str.replace rather than just .replace because .replace will only replace if it finds a match with the entire dataframe cell.  Here's a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ITEM_DESCRIPTION':  ['"ALICATE Cte Obl 6" 1000V - HAMILTON"',
                   '"SIM CARD TV LEASE P6"', '"more,." stuff"']})

df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"] = df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"].str.replace('[\",\.]', '')
df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"] = '"' + df["ITEM_DESCRIPTION"] + '"'

print(df)
#                        ITEM_DESCRIPTION
# 0  "ALICATE Cte Obl 6 1000V - HAMILTON"
# 1                "SIM CARD TV LEASE P6"
# 2                          "more stuff"
```